# How to get the user's Twitter status on Mean.JS

Tags: javascript, twitter, mean-stack, meanjs

JS to build a website which I want to get bunches of status of one specific registered user.

I have already implement the method of letting user signup with there twitter account through the passport-twitter, I think I should use the twitter package to handle this.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter

So now what should I do? Should I create a schema of database to store the status?

Now I have the file structure like this:

[image: twitter-file-structure]